# Angular5: Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for StoresComponent: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

After updating my project from angular 2.3 to angular 5 (and resolving many related problems) I get the error when starting my project:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for StoresComponent: (?, ?).
```

I have a StoresComponent with two parameters in the constructor. Both of them are own providers. If I remove all parameters from its constructor I get the same error for an other component:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for StoresUsersComponent: (?, ?, ?, ?).
```

I haven't followed further yet (removing the parameters from here, too and see what happens but I suppose there is something with my providers or DI configuration that angular5 doesn't like.) I got several search results saying that this is some kind of circulal reference problem but I don't know how can I detect what is referencing what?

My providers have the keyword @Injectable() and app.module contains the providers in the providers array. Unfortunately I had several other problems and I don't know what was the change caused this but I tried to move from `Http` to `HttpClient` according to the angular update guide.

One of the providers should be injected into the two components looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Store } from '../interfaces/store.interface';
import { StoreResultModel } from '../interfaces/store-result-model.interface';

@Injectable()
export class StoreProvider {
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}
```

storeusers.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";

import { NavMenuComponent } from '../navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { ProjectUserAddComponent } from "../modals/projectuser-add/projectuser-add.component";

import { StoreUser } from '../../interfaces/StoreUser.interface';

import { StoreUserProvider } from "../../providers/storeuser-provider";
import { StoreUserResultModel } from "../../interfaces/storeuserresult-model.interface";
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Title } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { Store } from '../../interfaces/store.interface';
import { SessionProvider } from '../../providers/session-provider';
import { AppProperties } from '../../app.properties';

//import '../assets/css/styles.css';

@Component({
    selector: 'storeusers',
    template: require('./storeusers.component.html'),
    styles: [require('../../../css/common.css'),
        require('./storeusers.component.css')]
})
export class StoreUsersComponent {
    public users: StoreUser[];
    private searchStr: string = '';
    private store:Store;
    private title = 'Felhasználók';
    private addMode:boolean = false;

    private countAll: number = 0;
    private countFiltered: number = 0;
    private orderBy:string = 'user.name';
    private backwards:boolean = false;

    private currentItem:StoreUser = {
        role: null,
        user: null,
        id: null,
        store:null
    };    
    private inProgress:boolean = false;
    private fieldsToValidate = ['roleId', 'userId'];  
    private formErrors:any = {};
    private searchInput = new FormControl();

    @ViewChild('maintopbar') maintopbar;
    @ViewChild('mainbottombar') mainbottombar;

    constructor(private storeUserProvider: StoreUserProvider, private sessionProvider:SessionProvider,
                private projectUsersEl:ElementRef,
                private router:Router,
                private titleProvider:Title,
                private appProperties:AppProperties) {
        titleProvider.setTitle(appProperties.NAME+' - '+this.title);                
        this.users = [];
    }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "node" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

Comment: can you show code for StoresUsersComponent and tsconfig.json file

Comment: @RRForUI I've included the beginning of the component and the tsconfig.json file.

Comment: There are many dependencies for this component. What you can do is, try removing injected dependencies one by one and drill down to one that is causing the issue.

Comment: What prefix do you use? Default is app ? Maybe that is a problem?

Comment: @RRForUI I've already done this on the StoresComponent which left me with the same error on the StoreUsersComponent. You say I may get somewhere if I remove dependencies from this component, too?

Comment: @stojevskimilan What prefix do you mean? My rootelement is 'app', my app.module is at 'app/app.module'.